# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'products' of 'productList' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to solve this problem but I can't do it, please help
https://github.com/yogeshmishra667/mern-shopping-App/issues/1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GOZF.jpg)

Comment: Please insert code instead of images.

Comment: You only need to add the relevant code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I create mern stack e-commerce website a tons of line of code here this reason I put the GitHub link

Comment: Key word is **relevant**. We don't need to know anything about the project except for the part that causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Concurrently and put at package.json like

"dev": "concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client"",

Do npm run dev at terminal  . That time both backend and frontend would run at the

same time . No more error then

Answer (score 0):

Probably, You are `destructuring` from an array i guess.
It's not possible.
We can only `destructure` from an Object. not Array.

Comment: This isn't true anyway, but the error even say's it' `undefined`, not an array... [Docs on destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, if `productList` is `undefined` you can't use [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on it.

The shortest solution is to give it an initial value using [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```
const productList = undefined;
const { products } = productList ?? { products: [] };

// Or
const productList = undefined;
const products = (productList && productList.products) || [];
```